# Replace string in one file with contents of a second file

Tags: bash, sed

I have two files:

- `fileA`:

  ```
  date >> /root/kvno.out
  kvno serverXXX\$ >> /root/kvno.out
  ```
- `fileB`:

  ```
  foobar
  ```

I need to create a new file, `fileC`, with the same contents as `fileA`, except with the string `XXX` being replaced with the contents of `fileB`:

```
date >> /root/kvno.out
kvno serverfoobar\$ >> /root/kvno.out
```

I'd like to do this using `sed`.

I tried some of the examples I found but I only get the contents of `fileB` in `fileC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1{h;d};/XXX/{G;s/XXX\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1/}' fileB fileA >fileC
```

EDIT:

alternatively:

```
 sed 's|XXX|'$(tr -d '\n' <fileB)'|' fileA >fileC
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this `EDIT` will break, if fileB contains a `|`.

Comment: Still, *for this question*, the fileB will contain neither `\n` not `|` :-)

Comment: can you explain this? I'm still trying to understand a lot of what sed is doing and can do.  Thanks
sed 's|XXX|'$(tr -d '\n' <fileB)'|' fileA >fileC

Comment: @jag7720 `s|pattern|replacement|` is a sed substitute command. In this case `XXX` is the pattern and the replacement `$(tr -d `\n` < fileB)` (note the single quotes either side) returns the result of  a shell process that runs the `tr` command on the file `fileB` and removes all of its linefeeds, thus presenting a single string as the replacement.

Answer (score 2):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "${line/XXX/$(< fileB)}"
done < fileA > fileC
```

Comment: @ruakh - +1: yes, it will fail with the posted input without -r and it will fail given other input without IFS=.

Answer (score 1):

There are some ambiguities with your question, but this works if I understood your requirements correctly:

```
#!/bin/bash

string=$(cat fileB)
sed "s/XXX/$string/g" < fileA > fileC
```

*Caveat:* `fileB` cannot contain `/`

**Explanation:**

- `string=$(cat fileB)`: save the contents of `fileB` to a variable called `string`
- `sed "s/XXX/$string/g": use`sed`to replace all occurrences of`XXX`with what is inside the variable`$string`. (The`g` part means replace-all)
- `< fileA`: input redirection - use `fileA` as input
- `> fileC`: output redirection - output to `fileC`

Comment: it will also strip any leading or trailing white space from fileB.

Answer (score 0):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line. For anything else, just use awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{b=b s $0; s=ORS; next} {sub(/XXX/,b)} 1' fileB fileA
```